# GAE app not displaying in Firefox

Tags: java, google-app-engine, firefox

My GAE app won't display in Firefox when i checked using view page source it was blank no html code and the web developer console displayed a warning

> [14:28:48.894] The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The >document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document >contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file >needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature. @ `http://localhost:8080/`

and the server log produce this trace

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at com.google.appengine.api.users.dev.LoginCookieUtils.parseCookie(LoginCookieUtils.java:113)
at com.google.appengine.api.users.dev.LoginCookieUtils.getCookieData(LoginCookieUtils.java:82)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalHttpRequestEnvironment.<init>(LocalHttpRequestEnvironment.java:50)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:475)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

I searched but found nothing please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear your browser cookies. You have a corrupted `dev_appserver_login` cookie. That'll resolve the stack trace, but (probably) not the character encoding issue. Maybe someone else has an idea on that.

Comment: you are right this cookie is the one creating the problem but the cookie is set when a user signs in , i checked the cookie in google chrome and it's working fine.